# Is IConfiguration passed by the DI Container in ASP .NET writeable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

The [Configuration dotnet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) says:

> Given one or more configuration sources, the IConfiguration type provides a unified view of the configuration data. Configuration is read-only, and the configuration pattern isn't designed to be programmatically writable.

However `IConfiguration` [exposes a setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#properties) for its properties, which I can use to add values to an instance of `IConfiguration` after it has been dependency injected into a class. I can then manually pass this instance into constructors and methods and have the set property be retrieved. In the example below I can pass `_config` to the constructor of `Bar`, which can read "MyKey" and return a suitable `Bar` instance.

I have observed through testing that each instance of `MyClass` seems to hold its own instance of `IConfiguration`; setting "MyKey" within one instance of `MyClass` one does not cause "MyKey" to be set in another.

However I thought I understood `IConfiguration` was supposed to represent the app wide configuration, collated from multiple sources and exposed to the application code as an immutable representation at start time. Is there anything documenting that my adding keys this way is safe, and that I won't set a value that could be read by a `Bar` constructor even if it hadn't been set by the `MyClass` that's creating it?

```
public class MyClass
{
  private IConfiguration _config;

  public MyClass(IConfiguration config)
  {
    _config = config
  }

  public Bar Foo()
  {
    _config["MyKey"] = "true";
    return new Bar(_config);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `IConfiguration.this[String]` setter is ultimately handled by `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot.SetConfiguration` which loops over every `IConfigurationProvider.Set()` - which is `virtual` and _most of the time_ it simply overwrites the in-memory value and _does not_ cause any write-back to persisted storage.

Comment: It's just an interface and the docu describes the behavior of the default implementation. You could have completely replaced it and implemented it the way you feared here. So for the default implementation you should trust the documentation that its readonly. If you use something else it could be different.

Comment: Besides that there seem to be people adding Configurations on startup(or try to) on the fly see https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/811 They need a setter.